# Best practice to avoid I/O bottleneck when multiple applications use JBOD disk

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, io, apache-kafka, disk

I am using bare metal boxes which run Kafka Spark HBase and Elasticsearch services. These bare metal boxes are connected to JBOD drives.

I see that my I/O bottleneck is unbearable.

So I would like to understand the following:
Kafka, Elasticsearch and HBase are I/O intensive. So does it makes sense to deploy these services on different boxes or it doesn't really matter if they are deployed on the same box. Deploying on the same box helps me in scaling out as I am using bare metal machines. Would there be race condition at the OS level when multiple simultaneous I/O requests are issued by Kafka, HBase and ES from the same box?
Appreciate your thoughts.